# How can I create a video from a background.png and list of image _*.png (each image_001.png, image_002.png)?

Tags: android, ffmpeg

How can i do this with FFMEG?

Input :

1. a background image : background.png
2. List of images frames: image_001.png,image_002.png ...(each image is a frame)

Out put: video.mp4 with all frames have backgroud is backgroud.png

I tried

Options 1 : 
create a video from frames and set background for video but result is NOT good . Frames in video Not transparent

Comment: Does the image sequence have transparency? Is is the same size as the BG?

Comment: @Gyan . Yes. image sequence is transparency and same size with BG

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it :

```
-f image2 
-i background.png 
-i img_%d.png 
-filter_complex [0:v][1:v]overlay 
-vcodec libx264  video.mp4
```